# how do I detect location service disable for my app?

Tags: iphone, core-location, cllocationmanager

IOS4 has recently introduced the possibility to **enable/disable** location services for a *specific* application.

I need to detect if this settings is **enabled/disabled** for MY application.

**First** I have tried with:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
       ....
    }
```

however this refers to the global location service and not to the specific application setting.

**Second** I have tried to use

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   ...
}
```

**It works** but it gets called both in case of service app setting disabled and in other cases like, for example, if a measure fails for some reasons.

**I need a code to detect if MY application is allowed to use location services.**

**How can i achieve this?**

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 24):

From the documentation for [locationManager: didFailWithError:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW4)

> If the user denies your application’s
>   use of the location service, this
>   method reports a kCLErrorDenied error.
>   Upon receiving such an error, you
>   should stop the location service.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if ([[error domain] isEqualToString: kCLErrorDomain] && [error code] == kCLErrorDenied) {
        // The user denied your app access to location information.
    }
}
```

You can find the other error codes [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW14).

Answer (score 10):

I prefer to use

```
-(BOOL)locationAuthorized {
  return ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized);
}
```

over the locationServicesEnabled property as it refers to the phone level, not your application.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apple docs on CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/locationServicesEnabled), there is a property called `+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled` that should do just that.

Comment: locationServicesEnabled is at the device level. authorizationStatus is for the individual app.